# Why does my plotly plot not display in certain conditions with plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am working with Plotly.js in a space where i need to dynamically change the data loaded in a plot.

The approach I took was to re-plot the plot div with new data that would be taken from a json. The data will be selected based on input boxes which will select the data from the json.

I have included a basic example in the snippet below.

How to reproduce:

1. Change the left selector to 'week'.
2. Then change the right selector to 'profit'.
3. Then change the left selector back to 'month'.

After this the plot will not display for this specific combination even though the correct data exists before the newPlot call.

However if you reload the snippet and then cycle through all the options in the right box initially and repeat the above process. It will work as expected.

Why does it only happen when selections are done in this order?

```js
var RevenueTrend = class {
    constructor(e) {

        this.data = e;
        this.periodicitySelector = document.getElementById('revenue_trend_periodicity');
        this.measureSelector = document.getElementById('revenue_trend_measure');
        // set default data
        this.#a('monthly', 'revenue');

        // set callbacks for boxes
        this.periodicitySelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            this.updateBySelector()
        }, !1);
        this.measureSelector.addEventListener('change', () => {
            this.updateBySelector();
        }, !1);
    }

    updateBySelector = () => {
        this.#a(this.periodicitySelector.value, this.measureSelector.value);
    };
    #a = (e, t) => {

        let r = this.data.data[t][e];
        let i = this.data.layout[t];
        let c = this.data.config;
        // Plotly.purge('revenue_trend');
        Plotly.newPlot('revenue_trend', r, i, c)
    };
}

let data = {
    "config": {
        "displaylogo": false,
        "editable": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "scrollZoom": false
    },
    "data": {
        "margin": {
            "monthly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Margin: %{y:.1%} <br> Month: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "Jan",
                        "Feb",
                        "Mar",
                        "Apr",
                        "May",
                        "Jun",
                        "Jul",
                        "Aug",
                        "Sep",
                        "Oct",
                        "Nov",
                        "Dec"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        0.0,
                        0.34047666529174736,
                        0.3457742367934246,
                        0.360425447773756,
                        0.35145317789771846,
                        0.35262465169115526,
                        0.36081828971765284,
                        0.3482103705232538,
                        0.3544357552302324,
                        0.3560519434681411,
                        0.3530277177894459,
                        0.3481856525787436
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "weekly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Margin: %{y:.1%} <br> Week: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "0",
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4",
                        "5",
                        "6",
                        "7",
                        "8",
                        "9",
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13",
                        "14",
                        "15",
                        "16",
                        "17",
                        "18",
                        "19",
                        "20",
                        "21",
                        "22",
                        "23",
                        "24",
                        "25",
                        "26",
                        "27",
                        "28",
                        "29",
                        "30",
                        "31",
                        "32",
                        "33",
                        "34",
                        "35",
                        "36",
                        "37",
                        "38",
                        "39",
                        "40",
                        "41",
                        "42",
                        "43",
                        "44",
                        "45",
                        "46",
                        "47",
                        "48",
                        "49",
                        "50",
                        "51",
                        "52",
                        "53"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        0.3525772625730744,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.32872302637273987,
                        0.31988710760016853,
                        0.6648776759648305,
                        0.36251039456330314,
                        0.3479492487227466,
                        0.36032892904889136,
                        0.35825354939402965,
                        0.3652140945623148,
                        0.35702058696618694,
                        0.3357665025509389,
                        0.35910528738699476,
                        0.3427007353759514,
                        0.34856822640364327,
                        0.37832888011952154,
                        0.34193158789278555,
                        0.35641605769889595,
                        0.3448526126036418,
                        0.3601298674795317,
                        0.34371914770696416,
                        0.35507083830741926,
                        0.35928883722389243,
                        0.3761116965344845,
                        0.3747882834748884,
                        0.3368771464780037,
                        0.34942511673599835,
                        0.3455765848399854,
                        0.3532858548316179,
                        0.36141903268210585,
                        0.3498830917602961,
                        0.3618410934198679,
                        0.3438166358418366,
                        0.34449309768685416,
                        0.356864537860347,
                        0.34723529927268637,
                        0.3676745634890173,
                        0.3618693942594029,
                        0.34298588976218763,
                        0.3352566880165647,
                        0.3604452053811187,
                        0.3747103844651644,
                        0.3606845347991698,
                        0.35760695701012907,
                        0.35939319863236174,
                        0.3143066542562211,
                        0.0,
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "profit": {
            "monthly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Profit: %{y:$.3s} <br> Month: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "Jan",
                        "Feb",
                        "Mar",
                        "Apr",
                        "May",
                        "Jun",
                        "Jul",
                        "Aug",
                        "Sep",
                        "Oct",
                        "Nov",
                        "Dec"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        0.0,
                        82241.71801566076,
                        698471.2893310541,
                        809776.0576551692,
                        905852.9974110408,
                        806949.604447975,
                        879519.9288410447,
                        826189.5344694187,
                        808316.6091934182,
                        906734.9758119395,
                        979581.009182293,
                        908955.4254592669
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Profit: %{y:$.3s} <br> Month: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2020,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "Jan",
                        "Feb",
                        "Mar",
                        "Apr",
                        "May",
                        "Jun",
                        "Jul",
                        "Aug",
                        "Sep",
                        "Oct",
                        "Nov",
                        "Dec"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        1135979.408899994,
                        964943.64602906,
                        995304.3674288283,
                        1024706.6108813051,
                        1103515.5129930207,
                        1015253.3387089209,
                        1031872.3701810606,
                        961556.9417143296,
                        960168.8140742977,
                        975513.6905591306,
                        940461.8968359237,
                        957659.4350654411
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "weekly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Profit: %{y:$.3s} <br> Week: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "0",
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4",
                        "5",
                        "6",
                        "7",
                        "8",
                        "9",
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13",
                        "14",
                        "15",
                        "16",
                        "17",
                        "18",
                        "19",
                        "20",
                        "21",
                        "22",
                        "23",
                        "24",
                        "25",
                        "26",
                        "27",
                        "28",
                        "29",
                        "30",
                        "31",
                        "32",
                        "33",
                        "34",
                        "35",
                        "36",
                        "37",
                        "38",
                        "39",
                        "40",
                        "41",
                        "42",
                        "43",
                        "44",
                        "45",
                        "46",
                        "47",
                        "48",
                        "49",
                        "50",
                        "51",
                        "52",
                        "53"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        53940.84905653694,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        112362.51304952896,
                        88316.08623819001,
                        -13591.410108961667,
                        363463.5909494356,
                        230162.22721852647,
                        205764.7039970004,
                        181015.46405094466,
                        191425.28083589178,
                        185312.97173273505,
                        179535.2064339334,
                        209365.34755655692,
                        189140.77872531046,
                        192786.1297563088,
                        210319.9968558866,
                        174347.49981516943,
                        233383.52298594668,
                        177403.35738587088,
                        192778.39938264445,
                        206603.86815812724,
                        205930.40940254647,
                        197144.6390165437,
                        181545.0009244157,
                        209428.82504632138,
                        189043.93557342276,
                        174954.73107864038,
                        186139.80161511753,
                        154918.25249529246,
                        235388.5039071208,
                        184606.3008933945,
                        191768.82369324705,
                        196552.9806996637,
                        166520.89121735393,
                        240248.02746187564,
                        195047.01679875085,
                        231842.86053096992,
                        185437.38300792413,
                        200771.21331067267,
                        230667.93972635642,
                        224753.03475951828,
                        211027.61818081193,
                        210132.7742313298,
                        240756.1128576225,
                        210571.98628046684,
                        193553.70303329843,
                        0.0,
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "revenue": {
            "monthly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Revenue: %{y:$.3s} <br> Month: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "Jan",
                        "Feb",
                        "Mar",
                        "Apr",
                        "May",
                        "Jun",
                        "Jul",
                        "Aug",
                        "Sep",
                        "Oct",
                        "Nov",
                        "Dec"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        0.0,
                        241548.76500916603,
                        2020021.2017193772,
                        2246722.762382407,
                        2577450.011491051,
                        2288409.5044913036,
                        2437570.250469525,
                        2372673.5456727156,
                        2280572.9875315665,
                        2546636.782767828,
                        2774799.1441469146,
                        2610548.1909645973
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "weekly": [
                {
                    "hovertemplate": "Revenue: %{y:$.3s}<br> Week: %{x}",
                    "mode": "lines",
                    "name": 2019,
                    "type": "scattergl",
                    "x": [
                        "0",
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4",
                        "5",
                        "6",
                        "7",
                        "8",
                        "9",
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13",
                        "14",
                        "15",
                        "16",
                        "17",
                        "18",
                        "19",
                        "20",
                        "21",
                        "22",
                        "23",
                        "24",
                        "25",
                        "26",
                        "27",
                        "28",
                        "29",
                        "30",
                        "31",
                        "32",
                        "33",
                        "34",
                        "35",
                        "36",
                        "37",
                        "38",
                        "39",
                        "40",
                        "41",
                        "42",
                        "43",
                        "44",
                        "45",
                        "46",
                        "47",
                        "48",
                        "49",
                        "50",
                        "51",
                        "52",
                        "53"
                    ],
                    "y": [
                        152990.15218077847,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        341815.1575488382,
                        276085.16923594667,
                        -20441.97090726295,
                        1002629.4318740314,
                        661482.1789769826,
                        571046.8613778194,
                        505271.9347990396,
                        524145.3812600044,
                        519054.0223673036,
                        534702.5539174988,
                        583019.3954535999,
                        551912.3806892863,
                        553080.0433114112,
                        555918.4294612729,
                        509890.0072076319,
                        654806.4205993534,
                        514432.40068988653,
                        535302.4472306541,
                        601083.3831528822,
                        579969.9304628688,
                        548707.9435582134,
                        482689.0591204212,
                        558792.3483215119,
                        561165.8064366985,
                        500693.0603984721,
                        538635.4567434222,
                        438506.80794771464,
                        651289.7291553597,
                        527622.8124217782,
                        529980.7765911351,
                        571679.6693633012,
                        483379.47069326247,
                        673219.1125022703,
                        561714.2531513739,
                        630565.4063498881,
                        512442.8480265313,
                        585362.8948114432,
                        688033.8199694896,
                        623542.8614506731,
                        563175.2599598169,
                        582594.3558914505,
                        673242.2514106827,
                        585909.7698058267,
                        615811.6616758438,
                        0.0,
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "layout": {
        "margin": {
            "title": {
                "font": {
                    "color": "#172631",
                    "size": 18.0
                },
                "text": "Margin Trend",
                "x": 0.5,
                "xref": "paper"
            },
            "xaxis": {
                "hoverformat": "%b",
                "tickmode": "array",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Date"
                }
            },
            "yaxis": {
                "tickfont": {
                    "color": "#172631"
                },
                "tickformat": ".1%",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Margin"
                }
            }
        },
        "profit": {
            "title": {
                "font": {
                    "color": "#172631",
                    "size": 18.0
                },
                "text": "Profit Trend",
                "x": 0.5,
                "xref": "paper"
            },
            "xaxis": {
                "hoverformat": "%b",
                "tickmode": "array",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Date"
                }
            },
            "yaxis": {
                "tickfont": {
                    "color": "#172631"
                },
                "tickprefix": "$",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Profit"
                }
            }
        },
        "revenue": {
            "title": {
                "font": {
                    "color": "#172631",
                    "size": 18.0
                },
                "text": "Revenue Trend",
                "x": 0.5,
                "xref": "paper"
            },
            "xaxis": {
                "hoverformat": "%b",
                "tickmode": "array",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Date"
                }
            },
            "yaxis": {
                "tickfont": {
                    "color": "#172631"
                },
                "tickprefix": "$",
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Revenue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

new RevenueTrend(data);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>My First Web Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="revenue_trend"></div>
    <div class="control-row">
        Periodicity:
        <select id="revenue_trend_periodicity">
            <option>monthly</option>
            <option>weekly</option>
        </select>
        Measure:
        <select id="revenue_trend_measure">
            <option>revenue</option>
            <option>profit</option>
            <option>margin</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try step 2 and then 1 and then 3.

Comment: @Hamzah yeah i guess so. But I am trying to figure out why its happening when I do it this particular way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long debugging, the problem is in the layout, going more deeply, it is with the type of x-axis which is months or weeks. The values of months and weeks are considered categorical values, not integer numbers. To solve this problem, please change **each** xaxis to the following configuration:

```
"xaxis": {
                "hoverformat": "%b",
                "tickmode": "array",
                "type":"category",  //<------------ add this line
                "title": {
                    "font": {
                        "color": "#172631",
                        "size": 12.0
                    },
                    "text": "Date"
                }
            },
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is impressive that you managed to catch that. I never would've guessed the issue was this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but you can solve your problem by passing a new layout object every time you create a new chart (instead of re-using the existing layout object):

```
let i = structuredClone(this.data.layout[t]);
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense given the issue was related to the axis type in the layout. Thank you for looking into it